# E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 error after copy file to other PC

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I just copy my project from my home laptop to my office PC with TortoiseSVN. But the project didn't run well in my office PC.

Here my code, I get stuck in here(I think).

```
public class SyncDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Handler mHandler = null;

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    private static final String TAG = "SyncDatabase";
    Context mContext;
    AlertDialog mAlertDialog;

    public SyncDatabase(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    String post_url = "http://192.168.56.1/php_poedi/progress_business/admin/process/location-Backup.php";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{
                String txtLatitude = params[0];
                String txtLongitude = params[1];
                String editUserID = params[2];
                String editEmailPHP = params[3];
                String tempRadio = params[4];
                String editDate = params[5];
                String nationality = params[6];

                URL url = new URL(post_url);
                Log.d(TAG, "checkpost_url: "+ post_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                Log.d(TAG, "txtLatitude " + txtLatitude + "txtLongitude "+ txtLongitude);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("latitude", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtLatitude,"UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("longitude", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(txtLongitude, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(editUserID, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(editEmailPHP, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("gender", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(tempRadio, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("birthday", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(editDate, "UTF-8")
                        +"&"+URLEncoder.encode("nationality", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(nationality, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "result: "+ result);
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
        mAlertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        mAlertDialog.setMessage(s);
        Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute: "+ s);

        if(mHandler!=null){
            Message message = new Message();
            message.obj = s;
            mHandler.sendMessage(message);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message " + message);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my error.

```
D/MainActivity: onClick: starts
    Date10/5/2009
    checkradiobutton Male
D/SyncDatabase: checkpost_url: http://192.168.56.1/php_poedi/progress_business/admin/process/location-Backup.php
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: Using Network Security Config from resource network_security_config debugBuild: true
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f100000 (t=15 e=0) (error -75)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: org.example.register, PID: 6130
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse XML configuration from network_security_config
        at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.ensureInitialized(XmlConfigSource.java:98)
        at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.getPerDomainConfigs(XmlConfigSource.java:65)
        at android.security.net.config.ManifestConfigSource.getPerDomainConfigs(ManifestConfigSource.java:49)
        at android.security.net.config.ApplicationConfig.ensureInitialized(ApplicationConfig.java:169)
        at android.security.net.config.ApplicationConfig.getTrustManager(ApplicationConfig.java:120)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManagerFactorySpi.engineGetTrustManagers(RootTrustManagerFactorySpi.java:65)
        at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactory.java:285)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.createDefaultX509TrustManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:933)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.getDefaultX509TrustManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:922)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.<init>(SSLParametersImpl.java:156)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLContextImpl.engineInit(OpenSSLContextImpl.java:100)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:316)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:671)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.copyWithDefaults(OkHttpClient.java:630)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkUrlFactory.open(OkUrlFactory.java:59)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkUrlFactory.open(OkUrlFactory.java:54)
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler.openConnection(HttpHandler.java:44)
        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:991)
        at org.example.register.SyncDatabase.doInBackground(SyncDatabase.java:66)
        at org.example.register.SyncDatabase.doInBackground(SyncDatabase.java:34)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f100000
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:1160)
        at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.ensureInitialized(XmlConfigSource.java:92)
        at android.security.net.config.XmlConfigSource.getPerDomainConfigs(XmlConfigSource.java:65) 
        at android.security.net.config.ManifestConfigSource.getPerDomainConfigs(ManifestConfigSource.java:49) 
        at android.security.net.config.ApplicationConfig.ensureInitialized(ApplicationConfig.java:169) 
        at android.security.net.config.ApplicationConfig.getTrustManager(ApplicationConfig.java:120) 
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManagerFactorySpi.engineGetTrustManagers(RootTrustManagerFactorySpi.java:65) 
        at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(TrustManagerFactory.java:285) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.createDefaultX509TrustManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:933) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.getDefaultX509TrustManager(SSLParametersImpl.java:922) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLParametersImpl.<init>(SSLParametersImpl.java:156) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLContextImpl.engineInit(OpenSSLContextImpl.java:100) 
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init(SSLContext.java:316) 
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(OkHttpClient.java:671) 
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient.copyWithDefaults(OkHttpClient.java:630) 
        at com.android.okhttp.OkUrlFactory.open(OkUrlFactory.java:59) 
        at com.android.okhttp.OkUrlFactory.open(OkUrlFactory.java:54) 
        at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler.openConnection(HttpHandler.java:44) 
        at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:991) 
        at org.example.register.SyncDatabase.doInBackground(SyncDatabase.java:66) 
        at org.example.register.SyncDatabase.doInBackground(SyncDatabase.java:34) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb25840c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb25835d0)
```

There is no edit on my project both of in my home laptop or my office PC.
I think the problem is in the Android Studio setting but on which part? I don't have any clue!

Here is my `network_security_config.xml`

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">

        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.example.register">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">    
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:label="@string/location_activity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="org.example.register.MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: show your `network_security_config.xml`

Comment: Check your network_security_config

Comment: please try and use volley or retrofit...

Comment: In Which target version are you calling API? If it's os version _8.0>=_ Then you must add this attribute `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` to manifest file within _application_ tag.

Comment: just add networ ksecurity and manifest. And my API is 9.0..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could see from your logcat, you are trying to connect to a local server for some location backup and hence you are calling an API to a server which is located in a machine having the following IP address `192.168.56.1`.

At your home, you might have a server application running which can only communicate in the local network. You need to have a public IP address for your server machine to access the API provided by the server, outside of your local network (e.g. your office).

As I can see from the logcat, you are trying to connect to the following host.

```
http://192.168.56.1/php_poedi/progress_business/admin/process/locationBackup.php
```

This is not reachable from your office network, as this IP address is the IP address of one of your machines in your home (i.e. local IP address). Hence, there is no resource found when this API is called and my guess is you do not handle the response when you do not get anything from your server.

Hence I have two suggestions.

- Make a copy of your server application as well and run it on a machine at your office. Get the IP address of the machine and put the IP address instead of `192.168.56.1`. You might also consider, setting up your home machine to have a public IP address, however, this will take a bit long time I think to be executed by yourself.
- Handle the response received from the API call gracefully. That is, when there is no response, your code should handle that as well. Generally, we can use a `try/catch` block to handle such situations. When a response from the server could not be parsed, you can get that in the catch block and generate a `Toast` or an error message.

Hope that helps!